# Pass symbols through MathLink with full context information

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, contexts

How can I ensure that symbols passed through MathLink retain their full context information?  When using MathLink naively, they do not.

Demonstration, controlling another kernel:

```
link = LinkLaunch["\"" <> First[$CommandLine] <> "\" -mathlink"];
LinkRead[link]; (* read initial prompt *)

foo`x; (* create symbol *)

AppendTo[$ContextPath, "foo`"]; (* add foo` to context path so now x refers to foo`x *)

Context[x] (* verify the context of x *)
(* "foo`" *)

LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[Context[foo`x]]] (* send foo`x to the other kernel and check its context there *)
LinkReadHeld[link]
(* Hold[ReturnPacket["Global`"]] *)
```

The other kernel thinks that `x` has context `` Global` ``.  It must have been sent without any context information.  I want it to retain its context, `` foo` ``, while being sent over.

It's the same situation when sending symbols back through the link: they do not retain context information.

---

I do have a sort of a workaround: temporarily unset `$ContextPath` on both sides of the link.

```
Block[{$ContextPath},
  LinkWrite[link, Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[Block[{$ContextPath}, (* code goes here*)]]
]
```

But this has obvious undesirable effects.  For example, what if the code that is being sent has `ToExpression`?  Parsing is influenced by `$ContextPath`.  What if the code sets `$ContextPath`?  Many things will break in obscure ways.  This can be made more complicated to fix some of the problems, but I am hoping for a better way.

If I do the same experiment with the parallel tools (`ParallelEvaluate[..., DistributedContexts -> None]`), I see that context information is in fact preserved.  So there must be a way to accomplish this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49342/discussion-on-question-by-szabolcs-pass-symbols-through-mathlink-with-full-conte).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I could come up with so far is the following code. It sends some `code` through `link` to another kernel for evaluation, then it retrieves the result.

```
linkEval[link_][HoldComplete[code_]] :=
    Module[{result},
      Block[{$ContextPath = {}, $Context = "myPrivateContext`"},
        LinkWrite[link,
          Unevaluated@EvaluatePacket[
            $result = code;
            Block[{$ContextPath = {}, $Context = "myPrivateContext`"}, 
              OwnValues[$result]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ];
      While[True,
        result = LinkRead[link];
        Switch[result,
          _ReturnPacket, Break[],
          _TextPacket, Print@First[result],
          _, Null (*Print[result]*)
        ]
      ];
      Replace[result, ReturnPacket[{_ :> expr_}] :> HoldComplete[expr]]
    ]
```

The `` Block[{$ContextPath={}, $Context = "myPrivateContext`"}, ...] `` is a hack to force sending fully qualified symbol names. I want this even for `` System` `` symbols because the link may connect kernels of different versions, so we set it to `{}` instead of allowing the default `` {"System`", "Global`"} ``.

We don't want to evaluate `code` with a special `$ContextPath`, so we evaluate it normally and assign the result to `$result`.

To prevent a second evaluation of the contents of `$result`, we send back its `OwnValues`. This is again done in such a way so that symbol names are sent with the context prepended.

This seems to work in most situations, e.g. evaluating `Sequence[]` returns as `Sequence[]`.  Evaluating `Unevaluated[]` also return as `Sequence[]` because several symbols we use (e.g. `RuleDelayed` in `OwnValues`) are only `HoldAll` and `HoldSequence` but not `HoldAllComplete`.  But the parallel tools don't do any better either.

Comment: To get fully-qualified symbol names, try something like ``Block[{Internal`$ContextMarks = True}, ...]``

Comment: @ilian Wow, thanks for pointing that out!  This stuff should really be documented to some extent, along with things like WithLocalSettings, InheritedBlock, etc. This doesn't even appear in the parallel tools source code.