# Context of SQLBinary in Package

Tags: contexts, databaselink

I have the following code for a simple key value store for binary data:

```
BeginPackage["keyValueStore`"];
{open, insert, get, close};
Begin["`Private`"];
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];

open[] := (
   $connection = OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["SQLite(Memory)",""]];
   SQLCreateTable[$connection, SQLTable["data"], {
     SQLColumn["key", "DataTypeName" -> "TEXT"],
     SQLColumn["value", "DataTypeName" -> "BLOB", "Nullable" -> True]
   }];
);

insert[key_, data_] := SQLInsert[$connection, 
  "data", {"key", "value"}, {key, SQLBinary[data]}];

get[key_] := Replace[
  SQLSelect[$connection, "data", "value", SQLColumn["key"] == key],
  {{SQLBinary[data_]}} :> data
];

close[] := CloseSQLConnection[$connection];

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

which one could use like this:

```
open[];
insert["one", {1, 2, 3}]
get["one"]
close[];
```

if you try this, you will find that inserting data will not work but throw a message like:

```
DatabaseLink`JDBC::error: "Illegal value: DatabaseLink`SQLBinary[{1, 2, 3}]"
```

now I can repair that by either doing:

```
BeginPackage["keyValueStore`",{"DatabaseLink`"}]
```

(which I don't want) or by replacing `SQLBinary` with `Symbol["SQLBinary"]` in the code. Both seem to repair a behavior considering the context of `SQLBinary` that I would consider a bug, but maybe just don't understand correctly what is going on. Would anyone agree that this is not as one would expect and should be repaired? Or can someone enlighten me why this is what I should expect?

Comment: What happens if you move the `Needs` to before the `Begin`?

Comment: But is ``DatabaseLink`SQLBinary[{1, 2, 3}]`` illegal or what? What should be the context of `SQLBinary`?

Comment: @Szabolcs: that will also not work. It seems to be necessary that either ``Databaselink` `` is on `$ContextPath` or that `SQLBinary` is created in the current `$Context`...

Comment: @Kuba: that are exactly the unclear questions. Of course ``SQLBinary[{1,2,3}]`` would be correct input given `SQLBinary` is in the correct contex. When I ``Needs["DatabaseLink`"]`` then there is a `SQLBinary` in the ``Databaselink` `` context so that would be the context for `SQLBinary` that I would expect to work, but obviously in the above situation it doesn't...

Comment: So it looks like DatabaseLink works only when it is in `$ContextPath`.  The reason could be that there's some string-to-code translation somewhere in the package.  Maybe through J/Link? A workaround could be to temporarily add ``"DatabaseLink`"`` to the context path while your functions is being evaluated  (using `InheritedBlock`).  But this still bothers me ...

Comment: If you look in the DatabaseLink package directory, interestingly you'll find a release notes file with a contact email address

Comment: I don't know any Java, so I won't write an answer. But I am pretty sure the reason is this:  Look in `SQLStatementProcessor.java`, lines 23 and 266. What happens is that the Mathematica expression is converted to a string, and this string is checked for correctness by some Java code. If DatabaseLink is in the context path, the string will be `"SQLBinary"`. If it is not, it will be ``"DatabaseLink`SQLBinary"``. This doesn't match the pre-defined string `SYM_SQLBINARY = "SQLBinary"`, so the Java code throws an exception.

Comment: @Szabolcs: impressive, what you have detected seems to be the explanation -- and for me looks like a bug, which even could be corrected easily. I think I should file a bug report, would you aggree?

Comment: @AlbertRetey they will probably tell you to always use the second argument of `BeginPackage` to import dependencies. The problem is that someone who will you your package may now know it.

Comment: @Kuba and Albert: If they tell you that you must import DatabaseLink in the second argument of BeginPackage, construct an example using this: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115502/12 In short, if you load your package, which has DatabaseLink in its BeginPackage, then DatabaseLink will be in the ContextPath. If you load a second package, which has your package in its BeginPackage, then DatabaseLink will be loaded, but it will not be kept in the ContextPath. The whole problem is that some DatabaseLink functions work only if at the time when they are called DatabaseLink is in ContextPath

Comment: thanks to both of you, I will file a report. Actually I don't care that much what the answer is as I have workarounds. I just think it makes sense to give feedback, be it considered or not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, the reason for the behaviour you observe is this:

Some DatabaseLink functions will only work if `` "DatabaseLink`" `` is in [`$ContextPath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ContextPath.html) at the time of their evaluation.

It does not matter how DatabaseLink was loaded. All that matters is whether its context is in `$ContextPath` at the time when `SQLInsert` is called.

---

The detailed reason is that part of DatabaseLink is implemented in Java, and some Mathematica expressions are being sent to Java through MathLink (J/Link).  This involves encoding the symbols making up those expressions as strings.  Whether they are encoded with or without a context prepended depends on the value of the current `$ContextPath` and `$Context`.

If `` "DatabaseLink`" `` is in `$ContextPath`,

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

ToString[DatabaseLink`SQLBinary]
(* "SQLBinary" *)
```

If it is not:

```
Block[{$ContextPath},
 ToString[DatabaseLink`SQLBinary]
 ]
(* "DatabaseLink`SQLBinary" *)
```

The Java code does some explicit string comparisons of some symbol names with `"SQLBinary"`, and fails if it finds `` "DatabaseLink`SQLBinary" `` instead.

The relevant code is lines 23, 110 and 266 of this file:

```
FileNameJoin[{DirectoryName@FindFile["DatabaseLink`"], "..", "java", 
  "com", "wolfram", "databaselink", "SQLStatementProcessor.java"}]
```

---

A possible workaround is to temporarily insert the required context in the context path in every relevant function in your package.

For example,

```
dbl = Function[expr, 
   Internal`InheritedBlock[{$ContextPath}, 
    PrependTo[$ContextPath, "DatabaseLink`"]; expr], HoldAllComplete];

insert[key_, data_] := dbl@SQLInsert[...]
```

---

Related:

- [Pass symbols through MathLink with full context information](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/132258/12)

Comment: thanks for the thorough inspection, I accepted it. It seems now very clear what happens and how we can implement workarounds. But I think you would agree that this has a strong smell of a bug, wouldn't you?